# Android an image I picked comes rotated

Tags: java, android

The photo I chose from the gallery comes automatically rotated. I tried everything i know like Picasso library but it didn't work. Some photos come rotated, I don't want that so what can i do?

Here are my codes:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) { 
        case R.id.imgCamera:
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            break;

        case R.id.imgGallery:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_REQUEST);
            break;
    }
}
```

To pick image:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                mPhotoEditor.clearAllViews();
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(photo);
                break;
            case PICK_REQUEST:
                try {
                    mPhotoEditor.clearAllViews();
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
        }
```

Comment: The photos are stored in an incorrect format. YOu need a way to get the orientation first

Comment: Hmm, how can i do?

Comment: `mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(bitmap);` Dont make a bitmap first. Try mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageUri(data.getData()); instead.

Comment: `The photos are stored in an incorrect format.` No. @Narendra_Nath . They are probably very nice .jpg image files. `YOu need a way to get the orientation first` Indeed. But why?

Comment: @blackapps First of, thank you for the comment. I used your code instead of "mPhotoEditorView.getSource().setImageBitmap(bitmap);" and now what should i do? I don't know "orientation" honestly.

Comment: You did not tell if using the uri directly solved your problem. That was my intention you know. And.. show the adapted code too. (And not in a comment).